# Camera battery consumption report

Tags: battery-life, camera

I am using a Xperia Z3 with android 4.4.4. I can't find how much battery is consumed by the camera app.

I tried with the included Power Management-> battery usage option but can't find it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android does not show *every app's* usage data; it only shows significant battery usage in apps, especially those of apps that run in the background -- **Camera** does not run in the background.

Try leaving your **Camera** open for a long time, then look in **Battery Usage**. *Note: Depending on your device, many apps my be bundled into the **Android/System** battery usage entry.*